# MS Word - Set ListFormat.ListType to Numbering

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have several numbering lists in a Word file. I need to set every numbering list to a specific layout. I have already coded a VBA that sets the correct layout.

My problem now is that the lists are consecutively numbered but I want every list to start again at 1.

Here is my code:

```
Function SetNumberingStyle()
Dim para As Paragraph, i As Long
  For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
    i = i + 1
    If para.Range.ListFormat.ListType = wdListSimpleNumbering Then
        para.Style = ("List Number")
    End If
  Next para
End Function
```

Comment: This should help: [Reset Numbered List with Text Style VBA macro MS Word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26266978/reset-numbered-list-with-text-style-vba-macro-ms-word/32623520#32623520)

Comment: i am relatively new to vba - how do i set the ContinuePreviousList to my list?

Comment: can anyone help me out?